# Rendering partial view ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, renderpartial

I want to render a partial view within the main view.

This is what I have done so far, but non of the code not loading the partial view.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

This is my main model

```
public class AppRequest
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
        public int ReqType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requesting By")]
        public int Req_By { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requesting Date")]
        public DateTime Req_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Location")]
        public int Req_Location { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Heading")]
        public string Req_Heading { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cover Note")]
        public string Req_CoverNote { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public int Company_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<General> General { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public  Purchase PurchaseItem { get; set; }
    }



    #region Purchase
    public class Purchase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("AppRequest")]
        public int Req_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual AppRequest AppRequest { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<PurchasingEmpl> PurchasingEmpl { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<PurchasingItems> PurchasingItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class PurchasingEmpl
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Purchase")]
        public int Purchase_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
        public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }

    }
    public class PurchasingItems
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Purchase")]
        public int Purchase_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
        public int Supp_Id { get; set; }
        public int Itm_Description_Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Unit_Amount { get; set; }
        public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
        public decimal Qty { get; set; }
        public string Recomandation { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public bool Settled { get; set; } = false;
        public string PoNo { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
```

And this is the View. My partial view name is **"_Purchasing"**. So under this **_Purchasing** partial view, I have added another 2 partial views. So I need to load this main partial view to show the other details.

```
@model Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AppRequest</h4>
        <hr />
     

        <div id="PurchseReq">
            @Html.Partial("_Purchasing");
        </div>

</div>
      
}
```

Comment: Is it `_Purchase` or `_Purchasing` You say one thing but then try to render the other? Is this just a simple typo?

Comment: To pass model to partial view, modify `@Html.Partial("_Purchasing",Model);`

Comment: @AjeetKumar then this error showed up `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest', but this dictionary requires a model item of type `

Comment: @phuzi Sory my typing mistake, the partial view name is `_Purchasing`

Comment: @smcdevelpments, then pass the modal as `@Html.Partial("_Purchasing",Model.Purchase);`

Comment: @AjeetKumar did pass the same but the same error again shows up.

Comment: @smcdevelpments, pls share the complete error message and the `Purchasing` partial view code. Pls make sure that the partial view expects a list of `Purchase` model

Comment: @AjeetKumar Hey Thanks. It worked. Don't know why earlier I have tried this `@Html.Partial("_Purchasing",Model.Purchase);` but I also got this same error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest', but this dictionary requires a model item of type` but again before I send you the reply i tried again by cleaning and rebuliding the solution and then this worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `@RenderPartial` and `@Partial`
`@RenderPartial` vs `@Partial`
As mentioned, you can incorporate a partial view in a Razor view by using either of two methods: `@RenderPartial` or `@Partial`. The difference between the two methods may look small and harmless, but it may bite at you if you don’t know how to handle it.
The key difference between the two methods is that Partial returns a HTML-encoded string while `@RenderPartial` is a void method that writes directly to the response output stream. The usage of the two methods is slightly different:

```
@Html.Partial("_yourPartialView")
@Html.RenderPartial("_yourPartialView")
```